# Raspberry Pi 1 Model A and Pushbuttons: Simple solution

Tags: electronics, pi-a

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A and am interested in attaching pushbuttons to its GPIO pins so that when you physically push the button, the button sends a signal to the GPIO pin that can then be reacted to in the software (running on the pi).

I'm new to electronics so I'm looking for the simplest setup possible. I watched [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEi_dT9KDJI) where the author just plops a pushbutton down into a breadboard and uses jumper wires to connect the breadboard/pushbutton to the pi's GPIO pins. I'd like a similar (simple!) setup.

I'm wondering what the make/model/specs are for that pushbutton so that I can buy the same one and attach it to my pi/breadboard the exact same way (or if there's a simpler way out there, I'm open to that as well!). Any ideas what the voltage/amperage ratings would need to be so as to be compatible with the pi (without the need for additional things like circuit drivers, resistors, transistors, etc.)? Remember, I'm a total newb here and simpler == better!

For example how about this: [On-Off-On-Off Alternating Power Button](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1684), maybe?

Comment: As long as you're using then with RPi GPIO, any pushbutton will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you referrer to is good enough.